# Is importing a file in python same as running that file?

Tags: python, import

I have 2 python files. file1.py and file2.py

file1.py

`print "file1"`

file2.py

`import file1
print "file2"`

and when i run file2,the output is

file1
file2

The question may seem little naive but i want to know what exactly is happening here.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
When importing a file it is being run.
To avoid this, file1.py can be:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    print 'file1'
```

And then the text will be printed only if file1.py is the main file being run directly.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense yes. When you import a file, you will run all the script and you will also initialize all the methods.

To ensure that code is only run when the file is run directly and *not* when it is imported. You should put all your main code in `main()` and do it as:

```
def main():
    #all your main code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The import statement combines two operations; it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope. The search operation of the import statement is defined as a call to the **import**() function, with the appropriate arguments. The return value of **import**() is used to perform the name binding operation of the import statement. See the import statement for the exact details of that name binding operation.

[import file using python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

To print 'file2' your code, you need to pass it as a command to the Python interpreter,

```
python myscript.py
```

there's no `main()` function that gets run automatically, so the `main()` function is implicitly all the code at the top level, and call `if __name__ == "__main__"`

[How main does in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)